# Помогите разобраться с навигацией в android-приложении

Tags: android, android-studio

MainActivity.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;

        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                navController.getGraph())
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
```

mobile_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/welcome">

    <navigation android:id="@+id/welcome"
        app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/preloader"
            android:name="ru.amgcompany.topcoal_2.ui.home.HomeFragment"
            android:label="@string/menu_home"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_preloader_to_loginFragment"
                app:destination="@id/loginFragment" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_preloader_to_registrationFragment"
                app:destination="@id/registrationFragment" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/registrationFragment"
            android:name="ru.amgcompany.topcoal_2.ui.registration.RegistrationFragment"
            android:label="fragment_registration"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_registration">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_registrationFragment_to_loginFragment"
                app:destination="@id/loginFragment" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
            android:name="ru.amgcompany.topcoal_2.ui.login.LoginFragment"
            android:label="fragment_login"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_registrationFragment"
                app:destination="@id/registrationFragment" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_main"
                app:destination="@id/nav_gallery" />
        </fragment>
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_global_welcome_to_main"
            app:destination="@id/main"

            app:popUpTo="@+id/nav_gallery"
            />
    </navigation>
    <navigation android:id="@+id/main"
        app:startDestination="@id/fragment_gallery">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_gallery"
            android:name="ru.amgcompany.topcoal_2.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment"
            android:label="@string/menu_gallery"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery" >
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_nav_gallery_to_viewOrderFragment"
                app:destination="@id/viewOrderFragment" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_nav_gallery_to_createOrderFragment"
                app:destination="@id/createOrderFragment" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/viewOrderFragment"
            android:name="ru.amgcompany.topcoal_2.ViewOrderFragment"
            android:label="fragment_view_order"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_view_order" >
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_viewOrderFragment_to_createOrderFragment"
                app:destination="@id/createOrderFragment" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/createOrderFragment"
            android:name="ru.amgcompany.topcoal_2.CreateOrderFragment"
            android:label="fragment_create_order"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_create_order" >
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_createOrderFragment_to_nav_gallery"
                app:destination="@id/nav_gallery" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_createOrderFragment_to_viewOrderFragment"
                app:destination="@id/viewOrderFragment" />
        </fragment>
    </navigation>
</navigation>
```

Не могу понять, что нужно скармливать `mAppBarConfiguration`, чтобы у меня в меню-гамбургере был только второй граф?

Ошибок нет, но меню не появляется.

Пробовал и по id графа отправлять, и набор фрагментов.

Если ошибка в **xml** - кните, как надо, пожалуйста, а то уже все остатки мозга сломал =(